# Recomponer dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un dataframe similar a este, pero con muchas más columnas (X0, X1, X2, X3...X23)

```
data <- data.frame ("X0ARVI" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "X0NDRE" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "X0MCAR" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7),
                    "X1ARVI" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "X1NDRE" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "X1MCAR" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7),
                    "X2ARVI" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "X2NDRE" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "X2MCAR" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7))
```

Y querría recomponerlo de la siguiente manera

```
data2 <- data.frame ("ARVI" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5, 0, 4, 2, 2, 5, 0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "NDRE" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "MCAR" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2, 7, 9, 9, 7))
```

Manualmente lo haría haciendo subsets que contengan X0, X1, y luego uniéndolos con rbind, pero no consigo hacerlo con un bucle que lo haga de golpe.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes usar `tidyverse` podrías implementar algo como esto:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(nr = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-nr) %>% 
  separate(name, sep='_', into=c("A", "ID")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID) %>% 
  select(-nr, -A)

# A tibble: 15 x 3
    ARVI  NDRE  MCAR
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     5     2
 2     0     5     2
 3     0     5     2
 4     4     5     7
 5     4     5     7
 6     4     5     7
 7     2     7     9
 8     2     7     9
 9     2     7     9
10     2     8     9
11     2     8     9
12     2     8     9
13     5     9     7
14     5     9     7
15     5     9     7
```

Detalle

- identificamos unívocamente cada fila con `mutate(nr = row_number())`
- llevamos todo a un distribución "larga" mediante `pivot_longer(-nr)`
- Separamos el nombre de las variables, para quedarnos con la parte que queremos agrupar: `separate(name, sep='_', into=c("A", "ID"))`
- Rehacemos la estructura "ancha" con `pivot_wider(names_from = ID)`

Comment: La segunda función me esta dando el siguiente error:
Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `X0_ARVI` <double> and `.geo` <character>.

Comment: ¿Pero como es el formato del nombre de las columnas, `X0_ARVI` o `X0ARVI`?

Comment: X0_ARVI, que se me ha pasado

Comment: Ok, ahí edité mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta con código R base:

```
col_names <- colnames(data)
new_col_names <- unique(sapply(strsplit(col_names, '_'), `[[`, 2))
chunks <- lapply(split(col_names, cut(seq_along(col_names), 
                                      length(new_col_names), 
                                      labels = FALSE)) ,
                 FUN=function(x) {setNames(data[, unlist(x)], new_names)})

do.call(rbind, chunks)

    ARVI NDRE MCAR
1.1    0    5    2
1.2    4    5    7
1.3    2    7    9
1.4    2    8    9
1.5    5    9    7
2.1    0    5    2
2.2    4    5    7
2.3    2    7    9
2.4    2    8    9
2.5    5    9    7
3.1    0    5    2
3.2    4    5    7
3.3    2    7    9
3.4    2    8    9
3.5    5    9    7
```

La idea es dividir las columnas en grupos de 3 o cualquier otro múltiplo dependiendo de la cantidad real de variables, construir una lista con `data.frames` parciales, unificar los nombres de las columnas y por último unir todas en un único `data.frame`

Comment: Y esta solución con R base también...



Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @JesúsMoraño, las dos soluciones que te pasé funcionan con el set de ejemplo que publicaste, sería bueno ver que diferencias tienes en la realidad con el ejemplo que has dado.

Comment: Sisi, muchas gracias, la primera solución tenía el problema de que dos librerías que estaba usando estaban teniendo conflicto, esta con R base no he intentado solucionar el error que salía, ya que la otra iba muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esta puede ser una solución:

```
df[rep(1:5, 3),]
```

**Output:**

```
> df[rep(1:5, 3),]
    X0ARVI X0NDRE X0MCAR X1ARVI X1NDRE X1MCAR X2ARVI X2NDRE X2MCAR
1        0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
2        4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
3        2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
4        2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
5        5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
1.1      0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
2.1      4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
3.1      2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
4.1      2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
5.1      5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
1.2      0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
2.2      4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
3.2      2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
4.2      2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
5.2      5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
```

Y una segunda alternativa con `dplyr`sería:

```
df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), 3))

> df %>% 
+   slice(rep(1:n(), 3))
   X0ARVI X0NDRE X0MCAR X1ARVI X1NDRE X1MCAR X2ARVI X2NDRE X2MCAR
1       0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
2       4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
3       2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
4       2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
5       5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
6       0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
7       4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
8       2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
9       2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
10      5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
11      0      5      2      0      5      2      0      5      2
12      4      5      7      4      5      7      4      5      7
13      2      7      9      2      7      9      2      7      9
14      2      8      9      2      8      9      2      8      9
15      5      9      7      5      9      7      5      9      7
```

Comment: Pero esta solución repite los valores de las primeras columnas, osea aunque el ejemplo igual pero por ejemplo: X1ARVI, fila 1, no es 0, es 1 por ejemplo